# Fingering for Eb Major in double thirds (piano)

Tags: piano, scales

I have seen a fingering for the Eb Major scale in double thirds where, in the RH, 35 is used for Ab,C is followed by 24 for Bb,D, but only when going upwards.  At first it seems better than using 13 for Ab,C, since it is easier to play upper notes legato, but since I had never seen 35 followed by 24, I wonder whether there is some long term disadvantage in using that fingering instead of the more "standard" one.

Comment: What source are you using for the fingers? From _Cooke, Master the Scales and Arpeggios_... Ab,C is 24 and Bb,D is 53 both ascending and descending.

Comment: I am using [these](https://www.musicandhealth.co.uk/Resources/Doublethirds1.pdf).
Note that the fingering I mentioned is only used in the upper octave.

Comment: For me, 12 would work well for the Bb-D. I customised this fingering because it was more suited for my hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For double note scale I collected a bunch of old method books from https://imslp.org

Scales in thirds seems to follow two different fingerings.

---

[Cooke, Mastering the Scales](https://imslp.org/wiki/Mastering_the_Scales_and_Arpeggios_(Cooke%2C_James_Francis))...

[image]

...where position shifts with repeat of the thumb `RH 12 13`.

In RH `Ab C` to `Bb D` is played `24 35` ascending and descending.

---

[Mason, Touch and Technic](https://imslp.org/wiki/Touch_and_Technic,_Op.44_(Mason,_William))...

[image]

...alternating `RH 13 24` except one `35` in each octave.

In RH `Ab C` to `Bb D` is played `13 24` ascending and descending.

---

It seems clear there isn't one, standard way to do the fingering. I believe both fingerings are intended for *legato* execution.

Personally, I like the Cooke method. As a general rule I avoid `1` or `5` on black keys except when both are playing black keys. That seems to fit the hand naturally, and the Cooke method seems to follow that logic.

The fingering in question...

[image]

...basically matches the *Mason* fingering, except that it starts with `24`.

I think the part in question is the in the red box.

*All* of the method I have seen *repeat the same fingerings at each octave repeat!*

The thing that strikes me as odd is that the fingering does *not* repeat at the octave.

Also, `35 24 13` ascending uses 3 consecutive cross overs which seems very awkward.

I really suspect this is just a typo! The part in the red box is probably supposed to be `13 24 13`. That would make all four octaves asecending/descending consistent. An alternate fingering *only for the second ascending octave* doesn't make sense.

Comment: I know the fingering I mentioned is uncommon. The question is, since at first sight it seems to work (in that it allows for more legato upper notes), whether there would be some long term disadvantage in using it for practice.

Comment: @Rui, I made an edit to my answer. I highlighted the particular fingering with a red box. I think it's a typo in the PDF! To me the disadvantage is the very awkward consecutive cross overs.